# InputStream to a list in Scala

Tags: scala, inputstream

I am trying to read a file as input stream and then convert the contents of the file into a list in scala. Here is my code

```
val fileStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("src/main/scala-2.11/com/dc/returnsModel/constants/abc.txt")
val item_urls = Source.fromInputStream(fileStream).getLines.toList
```

This does now work. I get a NullPointer Exception.
How do I correct this?

However, this works(but I cant use it in a JAR File)

```
val item_urls = Source.fromFile("src/main/scala-2.11/com/dc/returnsModel/constants/aa.txt").getLines.toList
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz Edited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

`getClass.getResourceAsStream` does not expect a full path, it searches for the requested file in the **classpath** using the same class loader as the current class.

Fixing this depends a bit on the structure of your project and class that calls this code:

- If the class returned by `getClass` is in the same package as the file you're trying to load (`com.dc.returnsModel.constants`), then you should simply reference the **file name** only:

  ```
  getClass.getResourceAsStream("abc.txt")
  ```
- If the class returned by `getClass` resides in a different package, path should start with a `/` which represents the root of the classpath, hence the package name must follow:

  ```
  getClass.getResourceAsStream("/com/dc/returnsModel/constants/abc.txt")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the correct path starting from root. 
Here root is start of your src/scala-2.11 folder in your case.

One example

```
object SO extends App {
  val resourceStream = SO.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/com/sm.txt")
  println(Source.fromInputStream(resourceStream).getLines.toList)
 }
```